# I wanna to to create and open Text file via Applescript

Tags: applescript

For now I can generate the text file with applescript with this code

```
    tell application "Finder"
  try
    set fileName to "untitled"
    if length of fileName = 0 then
        return 0
    end if
    set fileExt to ".txt"
    set thisFolder to the target of the front window as alias
    set newFile to fileName & fileExt
    
    make new file at thisFolder with properties {name:newFile, file type:"TEXT", creator type:"ttxt"}
    
    on error errMsg
    display dialog (errMsg)
  end try
end tell
```

but I want to open this new file that just created by the script instantly
May anyone suggest that ?

Answer (score 1):

To open the newly created *text file* immediately, you could change:

```
make new file at thisFolder with properties {name:newFile, file type:"TEXT", creator type:"ttxt"}
```

To:

```
open (make new file at thisFolder with properties {name:newFile, file type:"TEXT", creator type:"ttxt"})
```

This will immediately open the newly created *text file* in the *application* set as the *default* to handle this *type* of *file*.  By default, if it hasn't been changed, it will be opened in **TextEdit**.